# How to embed oidc-client login/login redirect in IFrame hosted in Reactjs client

Tags: reactjs, iframe, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I'm trying to work on a proof-of-concept to show that the redirect to IdentityServer4 can be displayed in a Reactjs app using an IFrame.  I realize there are security issues with this approach, like cross-site scripting, but again, this is a POC just to prove it can be done.  In .NET MVC I achieved this by creating a Controller and View that required authentication and then had the IFrame point to that view.  When the user was logged in the view would post a message to the parent stating that the login was successful.  However in React I'm using the oidc-clientjs library to handle the login/logout logic.

Would it be as simple as generating the login/logout URI and referencing that in the IFrame as the src?  I'm thinking that may work as long as the return URI that is configured in Identity Server is valid and points back to a page that uses the oidc-client-js to appropriately handle the response.  Any attempts I've made to embed the oidc-client-js signin redirect calls in the IFrame kick themselves out of the IFrame, I assume for security.  Even tried creating a React componenet but it appeared that immediate redirect call by the library wasn't allowed by React.  So I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions or even luck doing the same thing and could give me some direction.

Answer (score 1):

In the [SecurityHeadersAttribute.cs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/AspNetIdentity/host/Quickstart/SecurityHeadersAttribute.cs) file there are various protections added to prevent IdentityServer pages from being iframed.

I wouldn't recommend that you change these settings, they are there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks, should have mentioned I've added the necessary changes to allow the login page from IS4 to be displayed in an IFrame, Content-Security-Policy and X-Frame-Options.  I verified it by testing it on the MVC client site.